# Removing white space in LyX from table

Tags: tables, floats, lyx, white-space

I am using LyX and am trying to fit a table in the an A4 size.

I have managed to get the table in landscape however I am not sure how I can make it in the centre.

I already have tried using the Right Click - Paragraph Settings - Centre but it did not work out.

This is the backend of LyX:

[image]
 and this is the output:

[image]

As can be seen there is a lot of white space which I don't want to have. Anyone can help?

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @albert - I am working with LyX I am not sure how I can get this part can you help me? But my Document Class is Book Standard

Comment: I don't know LyX but I assume there must be a file where the source code is stored.

Comment: I'd recommend against the use of `resizebox`. As we can see in this example, the resulting output gets illegibly small (especially in comparison to the caption font size). Also I'd recommend to not use vertical lines and to just use a few well placed horizontal lines. This will make your table look more open.

Comment: Regarding the MWE: [LyX user questions on TeX stackexchange](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4488/134144)  might be useful.

Comment: Remove the resize box, reduce the size font and try again to center it. Then please remove all lines and in borders menu and select the "formal" style, then draw only 3  horintal lines (two in the first row and one in the last row).